# how to get input value and use it in async function for search in api?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a simple search bar for a movies website. How can I get a value from an `input` to use in an async API call?

```
searchMOvies.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  let moviesName = event.target.value
  console.log(moviesName)
})

async function search() {
  let response = await fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=[REDCATED]&language=en-US&query=${moviesName}&page=1&include_adult=false`);
  if (response.status === 200) {
    let data = await response.json();

    console.log(data.results);
    showMovise(data.results);
  } else {
    console.log(response.status); // 400
    console.log(response.statusText); // Not Found
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, it's REALLY not a good idea to make your API keys public.

Comment: Also, with regard to the problem, send `moviesName` as an argument to the `search` function. Your code will work fine once you've done that

Comment: `showMovise(data.results);`  make sure this ain't a typo

Comment: Also `searchMOvies` - js is case sensitive - should this be `searchMovies`?  *Always* check your browser console for errors

Comment: It work correct Idont know how to put  moviesName in search function

Comment: thank  you I did it   forget to return promise in serch function

Comment: Where / how do you *call* `search();`?  Change that to `search(moviesName);` or `search($(searchMOvies).val())` depending on where/how you call it.

Comment: I called in event listener  searchMOvies.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    let moviesName = event.target.value


    search(moviesName).then(r => moviesName)

})